# Filter by year and month in ndb model

Tags: django, nosql

what i am trying to do is that , i am using ndb model as my database and i have a model having  DateTimeProperty() property.
Now what i want is that i want to fetch all the records which for a particular year and also for a particular month.

```
class Photo(ndb.Model):
   userid = ndb.StringProperty()

   source = ndb.StringProperty()
   handle = ndb.StringProperty()
   sourceid =ndb.StringProperty()


   viewedCount = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
   likedCount = ndb.IntegerProperty()
   uploadedOn = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
   latitude = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
   longitude = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
```

i have a field uploadedOn which has a dateTime property.

queries would be like (i) fetch all records for year 2012 (ii) fetch records for month of January

I have value in format 
"uploadedOn": "2014-12-27T11:57:01"

Comment: Do you want two queries, one for year and another for month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
from_date = datetime.datetime(2015,11,30)
until_date = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
    Photo.query(ndb.AND(Photo.uploadedOn>from_date, Photo.uploadedOn<until_date))
```

Comment: Not working showing syntax error.
Can you please tell the use of int_filter_year and int_filter_month

Comment: Python date object has a "year" property which is an int, so uploadedOn.year should be 2016. Does  one clause works? Try Photo.query(Photo.uploadedOn.year=2016)?  edited the answer

Comment: It shows syntax error like :  Undefined variable from import: year

Comment: OK, try simple datetime, if it works I'll complete the answer. see the edits, for specific month

Comment: It does't works :(
I am trying something like this : Photo.query((Photo.uploadedOn).year==2012)
this query is also not working.

Comment: thank you for the help. your query works...it was my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
import datetime

date_wanted = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 27)
photo = Photo.query().filter(Photo.uploadedOn==date_wanted).fetch()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I think your query will only find entries for that particular day what if i want all the entries of year 2014. then what will be my query structure ?
Same is for the whole month?
Can you please help me out